# How to loop through specific rows, columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I want to loop through a specific range of my xls file. Shown on the picture you can see that I have some crosses on some points between the rows. I need to get their value into my python program to mirror them into an array. So I thought I just loop through the dataframe with pandas and make a simple if function.

my function looks like this so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xls', sheet_name='Tabelle1')


for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    if rows[index] == "x":
        print("test1")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gYZo.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: What is the question?  Welcome to SO please take the time to read [mre], [ask] and all the links found on that page.

Comment: So you want to reach specific columns right?

Comment: Pandas has [excellant documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html).

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question. ^^

Comment: @hamid.khb Yes, I want to reach the highlighted area and read out each row if there is an X or not.

Comment: is the columns have names you can reach them  through `your_dataframe["name_of_column"]` . there are some really short crash courses in youtube, which you can use to get familiar with the structure of dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xls', sheet_name='Tabelle1')
sliced_df = df.ix[8:26,]# slice base on the row index
for index, rows in sliced_df.iterrows():
    if rows[index] == "x":
        print("test1")
```

You can slice the pandas rows using ix. Google about pandas ix.